# Is it safe to adjust pot on sc-300 led driver by supernight

Tags: led-driver

Bought this the led driver (SC-300 by supernight) which claims to be a 12V 30A supply. I am drawing maybe 6 amps from it for what I'm testing. I noticed a pot on the side turning it changes the out put voltage. Any thoughts as to what this is for. Why allow the user to adjust output voltage if your only going to advertise it as a 12V supply? It seems to be able to output up to maybe 15V but. Ran it at 14 for a while doesn't appear to be getting too hot. Can I run it at higher voltages with out concern?

Comment: This information should be in the LED driver's datasheet.

Comment: Couldn't find a data sheet and I have searched several times

Comment: Good basic rule : no datasheet, no sale.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that as long as the total power output doesn't exceed 360 watts that adjusting the pot is safe. Maybe I should open the device up and look at the ratings of certain components, but I am not a power electronics guru. I'll update this answer with results.